# Is there a way to dynamically insert/add new fields that are not defined as part of the schema in a mongoose collection?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I am building a simple API and I have a registration end point where the user can register. I have a simple model with the username, email,name and password for the registration. When the user registers, I redirect them to the login page and once logged in, I have an edit profile endpoint accessible from the user's dashboard. I was wondering if there is a way in mongoose to dynamically add fields to the model that I already use for the registration. For instance I want to ad Job description as field to the model. Is this possible in mongoose or I have to set the fields when I create the schema and not have them required for registration?

Answer (score 0):

Turn off the strict mode which will allow any key while inserting into db. https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#strict.